# Is there anyway to add/scaffold a single method to an existing controller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ide

I am often building complex controllers within web apps that require a lot of methods within a single controller.

Scaffolding saves time and gives the bare essentials that I can then customise further to my needs.

I am always finding myself creating extra controllers for the required model then renaming and taking the edit/index (amongst others) out of there before deleting that controller and the associated views.

When you have code in a controller, you can easily right click and do `add view` to generate what is needed - I was just wondering if there is a quick way of doing this for a single method in a controller?

e.g. right click, select model, select action and name, then generate without having all the extra steps of renaming/deleting extra files?